# ShinyDashboard cannot create dynamic plot

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to create a dynamic plot for each of X variables against y for the mtcars dataset.
Basically, my y variable is "vs" column and the rest are my X variables
However, when i am trying to run the app i get the following error. Any ideas?

`Warning: Error in xy.coords: 'x' and 'y' lengths differ`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

data("mtcars")

y <- mtcars$vs
X <- mtcars[ , !(names(mtcars) %in% "vs")]


header_app <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar_app <- dashboardSidebar()

body_app <- dashboardBody(

  fluidRow(

        box(

          selectInput("filter", "Correlation", choices = names(X)),
          plotOutput("plot1", height = "250")

            ) #box
          ) #Fluid Row


)





ui <- dashboardPage(header = header_app, sidebar = sidebar_app, body = body_app)




server <- function(input,output){



  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({plot(input$filter,y)})




}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must extract the selected columns from `mtcars`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

data("mtcars")

y <- mtcars$vs
X <- mtcars[ , !(names(mtcars) %in% "vs")]


header_app <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar_app <- dashboardSidebar()

body_app <- dashboardBody(
  
  fluidRow(
    
    box(
      
      selectInput("filter", "Correlation", choices = names(X)),
      plotOutput("plot1", height = "250")
      
    ) #box
  ) #Fluid Row
  
  
)





ui <- dashboardPage(header = header_app, sidebar = sidebar_app, body = body_app)




server <- function(input,output){
  

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({plot(mtcars[, input$filter],y)})
  
  
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```